# syntax error in bash script unexpected token

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, startup

I have taken this example in this post [shell start / stop for python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686351/shell-start-stop-for-python-script) however I am getting a syntax error:

```
> : command not found 2:
: command not found 6:
'op.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'op.sh: line 8: `running() {
```

I am running CentOS 6.

Comment: Please post the code here in a [MCVE]

Comment: Looks like DOS line endings from the confused error message.

Comment: How should I convert that to be of an acceptable standard.  I wrote the code in windows and then pushed it over to a linux box

Comment: use `dos2unix` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getting this set of errors because you have an extra "Windows" character at the end of the line.

Usual Linux files normally end their lines with one char `\n` - meaning something like "next line" - whereas "Windows" files' lines end with the two chars `\r\n` - "next line - carriage return"... Don't ask me what the *carriage* is on a laptop those days.

This is a common issue, all of programmers will face in their life. See how [Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r) ranks for example!

There is a `Linux` utility to do the conversion between OS for you:

```
dos2unix myscript.windows myscript.linux
```

Comment: This is a good answer.  Please add more info so SO engine will not mark it as low quality.