# executing python script using bash

Tags: bash, python-2.7, shell, startup

I have tried to execute a bash start stop script however I am getting and error

> nohup: failed to run command `python2.7
>   /home/shopStart.py': No such file or directory

I am trying to follow this post [shell start / stop for python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686351/shell-start-stop-for-python-script) but have changed the start command to execute python2.7

```
/home/shopStart.py
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

script_home="/home"
script_name="$script_home/shopStart.py"
pid_file="$script_home/shoppid.pid"

# returns a boolean and optionally the pid
running() {
    local status=false
    if [[ -f $pid_file ]]; then
        # check to see it corresponds to the running script
        local pid=$(< "$pid_file")
        local cmdline=/proc/$pid/cmdline
        # you may need to adjust the regexp in the grep command
        if [[ -f $cmdline ]] && grep -q "$script_name" $cmdline; then
            status="true $pid"
        fi
    fi
    echo $status
}

start() {
    echo "starting $script_name"
    nohup "python $script_name" &
    echo $! > "$pid_file"
}

stop() {
    # `kill -0 pid` returns successfully if the pid is running, but does not
    # actually kill it.
    kill -0 $1 && kill $1
    rm "$pid_file"
    echo "stopped"
}

read running pid < <(running)

case $1 in 
    start)
        if $running; then
            echo "$script_name is already running with PID $pid"
        else
            start
        fi
        ;;
    stop)
        stop $pid
        ;;
    restart)
        stop $pid
        start
        ;;
    status)
        if $running; then
            echo "$script_name is running with PID $pid"
        else
            echo "$script_name is not running"
        fi
        ;;
    *)  echo "usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|status>"
        exit
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: It seems to be a problem of file locations .. can you show the files locations on your file system in the question?

Comment: @MohamedGad-Elrab I took the command and ran it in the ssh session, and it was running fine.  I have also done a pwd within the folder where the script resides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `python` command outside the quotes.

Make `nohup "python $script_name" &` as:

```
nohup python "$script_name" &
```

Otherwise the expansion of `"python $script_name"` will be treated as the argument file path of `nohup`.